# How to return False when using issubset and an empty set

Tags: python, optimization, set

When I have two sets e.g.

```
s1 = set()    
s2 = set(['somestring'])
```

and I do

```
print s1.issubset(s2)
```

it returns `True`; so apparently, an empty set is always a subset of another set.

For my analysis, it should actually return `False` and I am wondering about the best way to do this. I can write a function like this:

```
def check_set(s1, s2):
    if s1 and s1.issubset(s2):
        return True
    return False
```

which then indeed returns `False` for the example above. Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of how Python evaluates the truthiness of an object **plus** how it short-circuits boolean `and` expressions with:

```
bool(s1) and s1 <= s2
```

Essentially this means: if `s1` is something not empty AND it's a subset of `s2`

Answer (score 4):

I would do that like this:

```
s1 <= s2 if s1 else False
```

It should be faster, because it uses the built-in operators supported by sets rather than using more expensive function calls and attribute lookups.  It's logically equivalent.

Comment: How is that better than my approach, could you elaborate on this? E.g. Is it faster?

Comment: It will be faster, because it uses the built-in operators that sets support rather than using function calls and attribute lookups.  It's logically equivalent.

Comment: Ok, thanks (upvoted). Is there a good page for the `<` operator? I never use it for sets.

Comment: It's the `<=` you should use, actually.  Documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).  You should only use `s1.issubset(s2)` if s2 is something other than a set object, for example a list.

Comment: Ok, on this page it is written that both commands are equivalent (if I understand that correctly). Will do a few tests on time...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an `if` you can force the result to be a `bool` by doing this:

```
def check_set(s1, s2):
    return bool(s1 and s1.issubset(s2))
```

Comment: That should then also work without the `bool` (and would then be the answer @Mr.goosberry posted).

Comment: @Cleb it would, but I think I over-looked the fact that the return values could differ.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry: Yes, I missed that as well. (upvoted it now)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return the value? That way, you avoid having to write `return True` or `return False`.

```
def check_set(s1, s2):
    return bool(s1 and s1.issubset(s2))
```

Comment: Now you don't know the type of the return value, it will either be a set or a bool.  That's not ideal ...

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an empty set, you could use a set with an empty value:

`s1 = set([''])` or `s1 = set([None])`

Then your `print` statement would work as you expected.

Comment: I don't think he was trying to fix his print statement. I believe he was asking for a better way to return false in his `check_set()` function. (And I did not down-vote your answer)

Comment: Maybe @Cleb could clarify this?  While this answer changes the assumptions, it may simplify the overall problem.

Comment: I can clarify: @Mr.goosberry, is totally right; I would like to get an easy and fast way to return `False` in case I compare to an empty set. (I did not downvote either)